# Visual Studio 2017 C# Sockets UDP

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Im having a hard time figuring this out.
I'm trying to make a chat where there's one server and multiple clients but I can't seem to get it to work.

Im using Visual Studio 2017 and it's a Windows Forms App .NET Framework project. Now, it works but only 2 clients can connect to each other. If I try to connect two users to one, one gets blocked out of the conversation and can't recive messages from the server.

To the question: Is it possible to make a server that many clients can connect to and the server can send messages to all connected clients?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ChatProgram
{
public partial class Window : Form
{
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

    public Window()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); //Starts New Socket In InternNetwork Dgram Protocoltype UDP
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        IPMe.Text = GetLocalIP(); //Sets My IP Bar To My Local IP

    }

    private string GetLocalIP() //Gets Local IP From Computer
    {
        Send.Enabled = false;
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }

        return "127.0.0.1";
    }

    private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        try
        {
            int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] recivedData = new byte[1464];
                recivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string recivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(recivedData);
                MessageBox.Items.Add("" + recivedMessage); //Paste Messages In MessageBox listMessage.Items.Add(""+recivedMessage);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPMe.Text), Convert.ToInt32(PortMe.Text)); //MyPort And MyIP Make Port to Int32
            sck.Bind(epLocal); //Socket Bind To epLocal

            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpConnectingTo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(PortConnectingTo.Text)); //MyPort And MyIP Make Port to Int32
            sck.Connect(epRemote); //Socket Bind To epRemote

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            Connect.Text = "Connected"; //Set Text To Connected
            Connect.Enabled = false; //Disabled (Gray)
            Send.Enabled = true; //Enable Send Button
            TextBoxSendMessages.Focus(); //Set Focus To This!

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
            string nickandtext = NickNameMe.Text + ": " + TextBoxSendMessages.Text;

            msg = enc.GetBytes(nickandtext); //Messages The Sum Of Both
            //msg = enc.GetBytes(NickNameMe.Text + TextBoxSendMessages.Text);

            sck.Send(msg); //Send Message In Bytes
            MessageBox.Items.Add(NickNameMe.Text + ": " + TextBoxSendMessages.Text); //See yourself msg in msgbox
            TextBoxSendMessages.Clear(); //Clear Text Message Box
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void IPMe_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MessageBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Picture of program:
[image: SimChat]

[image]

Comment: A socket can have only one source IP and one destination IP.  So you need to open two connections.  See msdn :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx. 
 TGhe StartListening() will accept multiple connections in example.

Comment: @jdweng That didn't work, idk why but when I connect the clients to the server the server don't show up that the client has connected and when I try to say something in the chat it pops up a error message (check new added picture).

Comment: A server listens for a connection on a primary socket. When a connection is made a new instance of the socket is created using : listener.BeginAccept(   
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback).  So the BeginAccept gets the new instance of the socket while the StartListening method continues to listen for additional connection.  So when you get two connections the BeginAccept has to make an array of the sockets.  So when the server sends back a message it has to know which socket in the array to respond to.